# What does the "find" permission do in webextensions

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

On the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions I saw that one of the api permissions is `find`, but it gave no explanation of what it does.

I'm guessing that it allows me to retrieve the `Ctrl-F` find box searches, but I have no idea where to find the documentation on how to actually do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It lets you use this API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/find. If you don't request the permission in manifest.json, you don't have access to the find API.

Functions:

find.find()

```
Find text in a web page.
```

find.highlightResults()

```
Highlight the last set of matches found.
```

find.removeHighlighting()

```
Remove any highlighting.
```